# DB2 query in RazorSQL for getting the next val from a sequence

Tags: db2, razorsql

I am trying to run a DB2 query in RazorSQL for getting the next val from a sequence but getting the following error. Can anybody plz help me out.

```
VALUES NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ_UPLOAD_MASTER;
```

> ERROR: An undefined object or constraint name was detected.
>
> DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -204, SQLSTATE: 42704, SQLERRMC:
>   DB2INST1.SEQ_UPLOAD_MASTER Error Code: -204

```
Query = VALUES NEXT
VALUE FOR SEQ_UPLOAD_MASTER
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. I got the solution. I was trying with the wrong syntax. Correct one is

```
`select nextval for ARCH_TRANCHE.SEQ_UPLOAD_MASTER from sysibm.sysdummy1;`
```

Comment: Your original syntax was also correct, you just did not specify the sequence schema so DB2 was looking for it in the default schema: `DB2INST1.SEQ_UPLOAD_MASTER`, which equals to your authorization ID. You must have logged in as the user **db2inst1**.